# use epsilon delta definition of the limit to Prove that $\lim_{→2}^2=4$

Tags: calculus

On https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/2-5-the-precise-definition-of-a-limit, example 2.41, they used a Geometric Approach, which i find hard to understand.

I have 2 questions:

1.

They stated that Choose $=\min\{2−\sqrt{4−},\sqrt{4+}-2\}$, and uses $- \left(2 - \sqrt{4 - \epsilon}\right) \leq -\delta < x - 2 < \delta \leq \sqrt{4 + \epsilon} - 2$ to prove $\lim_{→2}^2=4$

But $\sqrt{4+}-2$ is less than $2−\sqrt{4−}$, so I think they  use $|x-2|<\delta=\sqrt{4+}-2$ is enough, take $=\min\{2−\sqrt{4−},\sqrt{4+}-2\}$ is not necessary.

2.

I used another method that differs from the textbook. Is my method correct?

$|x-2|<$
For $0<\epsilon<4$:

1. for $x>2$, $x-2<$

$x<+2$

$x^2 -4 < (+2)^2 - 4$

$x^2 -4 < ^2+4$

solve $^2+4 = $

$ =-2 \pm \sqrt{4+ }$

since $ >0$

$ =-2 + \sqrt{4+ }$

1. for  $x<2$, $2-x<$

$2-<x$

$(2-)^2 - 4< x^2 -4$

$^2 - 4< x^2 -4$

$|x^2-4|<\epsilon$

$-\epsilon<x^2-4<\epsilon$

solve $^2-4 = -$

$ =2 \pm \sqrt{4- }$

$ =2 - \sqrt{4- }$

For $2<x$, for every $*0<ϵ<4*$, there exists a $*0<δ=-2 + \sqrt{4+ }*$

$0<∣x−2∣<-2 + \sqrt{4+ }$

$0<x−2<-2 + \sqrt{4+ }$

$2<x<\sqrt{4+ }$

$0<x^2-4<\epsilon$

$|x^2-4|<\epsilon$

For $x<2$, for every $*0<ϵ<4*$, there exists a $*0<δ=2 - \sqrt{4- }*$

$0<∣x−2∣<2 - \sqrt{4- }$

$0<2-x<2 - \sqrt{4- }$

$-2<-x<-\sqrt{4- }$

$2>x>\sqrt{4- }$

$0>x^2-4>-$

$|x^2-4|<\epsilon$

such that if $0<∣x−2∣<δ$, then $∣x^2−4∣<ϵ$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, then for all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that if $|x-a|\lt \delta$, $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$. If $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=2$ and $L=4$, this implies that for all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that if $|x-2|\lt \delta$, $|x^2-4|\lt \epsilon$

Working backwards, $|x^2-4|\lt\epsilon$ implies $-\epsilon\lt x^2-4\lt \epsilon$ which in turn implies $4-\epsilon\lt x^2 \lt 4+\epsilon$. Taking the positive square root yields $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\lt x \lt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}$. Then subtracting $2$ gives us $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}-2\lt x-2\lt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$.

We have found the desired form of our first $\delta$. Let's call it $\delta_1$. If $|x-2|\lt \delta_1$ then $|x-2|\lt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$, which implies that $2-\sqrt{4+\epsilon}\lt x-2 \lt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$. This implies that $x\lt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}$ and from there that $x^2\lt 4+\epsilon$, allowing us to conclude that $x^2-4\lt \epsilon$, which is what we wanted to show.

All well and good, but what about the other value of $\delta$? That comes from taking the negative square root instead ofs the positive one. Going back a few steps, we had $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}-2\lt x-2 \lt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$. If we take the negative square root instead, we will have $2-\sqrt{4+\epsilon}\lt 2-x \lt 2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$. We may change $x-2$ to $2-x$ because of the fact that order is preserved under multiplication (albeit reversed under multiplication by negative numbers), and because of the fact that for all reals $b$ and $c$, $|b-c|=|c-b|$ and $|b^2|=|(-b)^2|$.

Thus we have found our $\delta_2$. To check that it works, we again use the condition: that if $|x-2|\lt \delta_2$, $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$. If $|x-2|\lt \delta_2$, then $2-x\lt 2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$, which means that $-x\lt -\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$. This in turn means that $x^2\lt 4-\epsilon$, from which you can conclude that $x^2-4\lt -\epsilon$. Since $|-b|=-b$ for all $b$ greater than zero, we may simply take the absolute value without changing the order, so that we end up with $|x^2-4|\lt |\epsilon|=\epsilon$

Now you were also wondering why we had to take a minimum of two values for $\delta$. The answer to that is simply this: it may not always be true that $2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\gt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$ which can be seen by solving this inequality first for $\epsilon$ and then by reversing the inequality and solving *that* for epsilon. Solving this inequality first yields the following:

$$2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\gt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$4-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\gt\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$$
$$4-\epsilon-8\sqrt{4-\epsilon}+16\gt 4+\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$-8\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\gt2\epsilon-16$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$64(4-\epsilon)\gt 4\epsilon^2-32\epsilon+256$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$0\gt 4\epsilon^2+96\epsilon$$

The term on the right is a quadratic in $\epsilon$ with a positive leading coefficient; in graphical terms, it is represented by an upward-opening parabola. The values of $\epsilon$ for which its graph lies below $y=0$ are those which lie between its roots, which occur at $0$ and $24$. Thus the statement that $2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\gt \sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2$ is true only when $0\lt\epsilon \lt 24$. Outside of that, the statement $\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2\geq  2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$ is true instead - in fact, outside the interval $[-4,4]$, one of the expressions will be undefined altogether! Anyway, since $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ can be anything (within that interval), we are forced to choose a value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, I think there are some mistakes in your solution, you stated:
$-8\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\gt2\epsilon-16$
$\Rightarrow$
$64(4-\epsilon)\gt 4\epsilon^2-32\epsilon+256$

But both $-8\sqrt{4-\epsilon}$ and $2\epsilon-16$ are less than zero, so the you should change the direction of the sign:
$64(4-\epsilon)< 4\epsilon^2-64\epsilon+256$
The result should be $0<4\epsilon^2$.